# Why" sub esp, 96", "lea eax, [esp+16]" and "mov [esp+4], eax"? (asm intel syntax)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn assembly (Intel syntax) by reverse engineering assembly code created by GNU with the help of IDA. I have an extremely hard time to understand references to memory addresses in Assembly and would really appreciate if someone could comment the code below and explain what is really happening.

It's the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *input[20];

    scanf("%s", &input);
    printf("%s", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Assembly with Intel syntax:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

and     esp, -16
sub     esp, 96                             ; char *input[20]

                                            ; scanf("%s", &input)
lea     eax, [esp+16]                       ; move the effective address of [esp+16] into EAX
mov     [esp+4], eax                        ; &input
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset aS          ; %s
call    _scanf

                                            ; printf("%s", input)
lea     eax, [esp+10]                       ; move the effective address of [esp+10] into EAX
mov     [esp+4], eax                        ; input
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset aS          ; %s
call    _printf     

mov     eax, 0
leave
ret
```

**Question 1:**
Why has the compiler subtracted 96 from ESP when the variable contains 20? What are all the extra bytes for and how did the compiler end up on that number?

```
sub     esp, 96
```

**Question 2:**
Why did the compiler choose ESP+16? Why not, for example, ESP+5 or ESP+10?

```
lea     eax, [esp+16]
mov     [esp+4], eax
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Both of those depend on compiler internals and optimization settings and are not really of interest.

Comment: No, it's correct.

Comment: @Lavonen Is that supposed to be a reply to me? The code is clearly wrong as any C programmer past beginner level (and the compiler) can tell you. Don't make such baseless assertions when you don't have the knowledge or experience to back it up.

Comment: Your code is definitely wrong. Margaret has answered that `input` is an array of 20 pointers, not an array of 20 characters, so you reading text into it invokes UB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(input)` is likely to be 80 since `input` is declared as `char *input[20]` i.e. and array 20 of pointers (each of 4 bytes).

This particular compiler (GNU is not a compiler) is aligning the stack on 16 bytes (i.e. keeping the stack pointer at an offset multiple of 16) and *allocating the space for the parameters all at once in the prolog* instead of `push`ing them per-call and then `add esp`ing to clean the stack (see the `_cdecl` calling convention).
The compiler could just use 8 bytes for the parameters (for a total of `88` bytes allocated) but 88 is not multiple of 16, the next multiple of 16 is 96.

`esp` is where to put the first parameter, `esp+4` the second, `esp+8` and `esp+12` are padding for the alignment, `esp+16` to `esp+96` are the 80 bytes of the array.

`esp+5` or `esp+10` are not suitable because this is not where the callee expects to find the arguments.

Drawing the stack on a piece of paper will greatly clarify the matter.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation))